# DirectorySearcher doesn't respect the SizeLimit property if the SizeLimit is 256 or over

Tags: c#, active-directory, directorysearcher, principalsearcher

I'm using `PrincipalSearcher` and `DirectorySearcher` to filter users and specify which properties to grab. On testing it on 2 different networks. One network has 8K+ records and the other has 135K+. On the 135K+ network, it fails to save the records to a database. So I want to do a test with a handful of records, but it doesn't fail on the couple hundred of records I've tried. So I tried increasing it to a thousand. But when I do that, it gives me everything instead of the thousand I requested.

Here's how I'm doing this:

```
using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
    DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
    directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectSid=*)(sn=*)(givenName=*)(objectGuid=*))";
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ObjectGUID");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName");
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("countryCode");
    directorySearcher.SizeLimit = 255;
```

Notice the size limit here is 255. If I specify a value under 256, it will return the number of I records I specify. Quick example of it in action on the small network:

[image]

If I tell it to give me 255 records, it gives me 255 records. But if I tell it to give me 256 or higher, it wants to give me all of them.

[image]

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `PageSize` property on the `DirectorySearcher` object. It seems like the page size was limited when a non-default value was set to the `SizeLimit` property. I set the `PageSize` property to 4000 and any value I put in the SizeLimit pulled that exact number.